# Shinobi Charts SChartCategoryAxis and SChartLineSeries cut in middle last tick mark label

Tags: ios, charts, shinobi

I'm using Shinobi charts for iOS with xAxis as SChartCategoryAxis and yAxis as SChartNumberAxis.

The data is shown as an SChartLineSeries. xAxis is supposed to show the 7 days of a week Mon,Tue,...,Sun. The problem is that the label for Sunday (Sun) is not displayed correctly but cut in middle.

Since i do not have enough reputation, i can not attach a screenshot but the issue can easily be reproduced.

I should say that i can not use SChartDateTimeAxis for my real data. This is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be altered by setting xAxis.rangePaddingHigh to a sufficient value, such as @10, which will give you a padding of 10 at the top of the axis.

Hope this helps!
Rob

Comment: Setting xAxis.rangePaddingHigh=@1 seems to be enough because xAxis is of type SChartCategoryAxis!